# SAS Regression Returns 0 Coefficient

Tags: sas, regression, linear-regression

I am running a SAS regression using the following model:

```
  ods output ParameterEstimates=stock_params;
  proc reg data=REG_DATA;
    by SYMBOL DATE; 
    model RETURN_SEC = market_premium;
  run;
  ods output close;
```

Where RETURN_SEC is the return of the stock per second and market_premium is the return of SPY index minus the risk free rate (the risk free rate is quite close to zero because it is at a second level).

However, I got lots of 0s (not all of them, but a significant number of) in the coefficient of market_premium. When I check the log it says:

```
NOTE: Model is not full rank. Least-squares solutions for the parameters are
      not unique. Some statistics will be misleading. A reported DF of 0 or B
      means that the estimate is biased.
NOTE: The following parameters have been set to 0, since the variables are a
      linear combination of other variables as shown.


                     market_premium =  - 19E-12 * Intercept
```

This is quite weird. I checked the data and it seems fine (although lot of data contains 0 return_sec, which is normal because sometimes the return doesn't change in seconds but in minutes).

What also puzzles me is that why SAS would return 0 coefficient on market_premium when market_premium =  - 19E-12 * Intercept. I mean, does SAS treat the Intercept as the only variable when it sees that market_premium is a scalar times of Intercept?

Comment: Is it saying that `market_premium` can be ignored as the intercept term fully explains it?   (I'd also note that `19e-12` is awfully close to the lower limit of precision in SAS and so not all that different from 0 itself...)

Comment: If the intercept term fully explains it, then basically return_sec is a constant? That doesn't make much sense though, unless return_sec is too small and it cannot be estimated.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what that would mean, I believe (though I'm not a statistician).  You might be better asking this on [stats.se] as this seems like it's less a "how to do this in SAS" question and more a general question about statistics - unless you think you did this wrong, anyway. I will say I'm not sure `BY DATE` is appropriate; do you really want each DATE to be separately analyzed?  Or is this more of a time series.

Comment: Really this sounds more to me like you might have a data problem, though.  Have you standardized and normalized your data?  All these 0's in return_sec could be an issue, I could definitely see.  If your data doesn't show at the second level, then maybe you should sum it up to the minute level?  Use ETS (`proc expand` or similar) to make it right.

Comment: Your 'by' variable for "date" is most likely causing the issue. This would mean you're individually trying to make a regression for each symbol and date, which is probably incorrect (unless you have multiple observations for an individual stock/date combo). You should be using a time-series proc to turn it into a valid time-series, and then create your model using `proc arima` or another ETS proc.

Comment: See this cross validated question on rank defficiency: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/

Comment: Looking at the big picture, it's rare for a stock price to change that much in day, IMO most would look more similar to a random walk than anything else. So I'd expect a heck a lot of 0's. Especially at the second level.